# How to disable kubectl auto-completions on zsh

Tags: kubernetes, autocomplete, zsh, kubectl, zsh-completion

How can I disable the kubectl autocompletions functionality on zsh. I'm running on osx and the autocompletions are slow(probably because they have to call the remote cluster API) and I don't want them no more.

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#enabling-shell-autocompletion)? Have you tried to edit your `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: Also .. don't press tab then ^^ ... maybe a too simple proposal as you could use auto completion when you need it still.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, autocompletion in `kubectl` command is not enabled by default. You needed to enable it beforehand. To disable it would be best just to reverse the steps you took to enable it.

### How to enable autocompletion for `kubectl` within `zsh` environment:

---

> The kubectl completion script for Zsh can be generated with the command  `kubectl completion zsh`. Sourcing the completion script in your shell enables kubectl autocompletion.
>
> To do so in all your shell sessions, add the following to your  `~/.zshrc`  file:
>
> ```sh
> $ source <(kubectl completion zsh)
> ```
>
> --  [Kubernetes.io: Enabling shell autocompletion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#enabling-shell-autocompletion)

Following above example:

Command `$ source <(kubectl completion zsh)`:

- can be run by itself in shell for autocompletion within current session
- **can be put in  `~/.zshrc`  file to be loaded each time user logs in**

After applying one of above solutions it should provide available options with `TAB` keypress to type into terminal like below:

```sh
somefolder% kubectl get pod[TAB PRESSED HERE!]
poddisruptionbudgets.policy     pods.metrics.k8s.io             podsecuritypolicies.policy      
pods                            podsecuritypolicies.extensions  podtemplates
```

### How to disable autocompletion for `kubectl` within `zsh` environment:

---

As said above autocompletion is not enabled by default. It can be disabled:

- when created for current session by:

  - creating a new session (example `zsh`)
- **when edited `~/.zshrc` file by:**

  - removing: `source <(kubectl completion zsh)`  from `~/.zshrc` file.
  - creating a new session (example `zsh`)

**After that autocompletion for `kubectl` should not work.**

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.